# How to use AuthenticationInfo in xWebApplication DSC resource

Tags: powershell, dsc

I have the following in my DSC configuration:

```
        xWebApplication StaffDirectoryApp {
            Website = "MySite"
            Name = "MyApp"
            WebAppPool = "MyPool"
            PhysicalPath = $Destination
            Ensure = "Present"
            PreloadEnabled = $true
        }
```

This seems to be working ok, but I also want to use the AuthenticationInfo property (although documentation seems to say it should be AuthenticationInformation, it's not).

The only example I can find is in one of the unit tests on GitHub, and their usage is something like this:

```
AuthenticationInfo = New-CimInstance -ClassName MSFT_xWebApplicationAuthenticationInformation `
                        -ClientOnly `
                        -Property @{ Anonymous = $false; Basic = $false; Digest = $false; Windows = $true }
```

This, however, yields the following:

```
Convert property 'AuthenticationInfo' value from type 'STRING' to type 'INSTANCE' failed
```

How should I set this property?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following syntax:

```
   xWebApplication StaffDirectoryApp {
        Website = "MySite"
        Name = "MyApp"
        WebAppPool = "MyPool"
        PhysicalPath = $Destination
        Ensure = "Present"
        PreloadEnabled = $true
        AuthenticationInfo = MSFT_xWebApplicationAuthenticationInformation
        {
        Anonymous = $false
        Basic = $false
        Digest = $false
        Windows = $true
        }
   }
```

I don't know why the code with `New-CimInstance` doesn't work, but this one should to the trick.